# LEGO WeDo and Mac OS X Lion

Tags: software, wedo

Just got a new Mac with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion instead of burned old one. Now I can't install WeDo software since its installer doesn't support Lion. Google search suggests that LEGO released a patch to installer that solves this problem, but all links are broken. Any help in adapting WeDo software to Lion is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [this is the current location for the Lion Patch
[image: MAC OS 10.7 (Lion) Installer Fix]](http://cache.lego.com/r/education/-/media/LEGO%20Education/Home/Downloads/Software/Updates/WeDo/ts.20120203T091708.WeDo%20Lion%20Patch%20Feb%2012.zip)

In the interests of finding it again when the LEGO group change their site again:

1. Visit the [LEGO Education page](http://education.lego.com/en-gb/).
2. Navigate to "Pre-school and School" -> Secondary -> 11+ LEGO MINDSTORMS Education -> Downloads (or similar)
   [image: Deep Menus]
3. I then filtered the list to just the Download Type of "Software Update / Patch".

Answer (score 1):

The solution just lain on the surface! To install WeDo you should open Support folder in DMG image and DIRECTLY click on English or yourlanguage.mpkg to launch installation program.[image]